# Adding Recent Comments in a side panel in Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I create a left-hand side panel that contains, among others (such as Recent Posts), also a section to display the Recent Comments.
I have difficulties to make this work.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
{% load comment_tags %}
...
{% block recent_comments %}
{% recent_comments 5 as last_comments %}
{% if last_comments %}
...
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I get `VariableDoesNotExist` error on line `{% recent_comments 5 as last_comments %}`

How can I implement such a "Recent Comments" section ?

Thank you,

GG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you get this code?  Mezzanine's `recent_comments` tag is a inclusion tag which works in the different way:

```
{% recent_comments %}
```

And you should define the [`COMMENT_NUM_LATEST`](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/docs/settings.rst#comments_num_latest) setting in the `settings.py`.

If you want to get the list of last comments then you have to create custom [assignment template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags):

```
from mezzanine import template
from mezzanine.generic.models import ThreadedComment

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_recent_comments(num):
    return ThreadedComment.objects.all().select_related(depth=1) \
                                  .order_by("-id")[:num]
```

Comment: Can you please explain where to put this code? Your first line of code seems to belong in a Django template file, but the longer code block doesn't. Presumably it goes in a Python file inside one of the templatetags directories, but it would be good to have this clarified.

Comment: Yes, this code should be in the `templatetags` dir.  See the "Code layout" chapter of the django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: Thanks. I'll upvote the answer if you edit the extra guidance into it.